# For any $X\subset \mathbb{R}$, is $|X|<|\mathbb{R}|, |X|\leq|\mathbb{R}|,$ or $|X|=|\mathbb{R}|$?

Tags: real-analysis

So take for example $(20,35) \subset \mathbb{R}$

$(20,35)$ has an infinite number of elements and is uncountable

$\mathbb{R}$ has an infinite number of elements and is uncountable

Can we find a function $f:(20,35)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that maps every element of the domain to the codomain?

Or is the infinity posed by $|\mathbb{R}|$ bigger than the infinity posed by $|(20,35)|$?

Like, for example, we know that $|\mathbb{N}|<|\mathbb{R}|$ since for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find an $x \in \mathbb{R}:n<x<n+1$, thus $|\mathbb{N}|<|\mathbb{R}|$

I would like to think that since $(20,35)\subset\mathbb{R}$, that by design, $|(20,35)|< |\mathbb{R}|$ but the uncountability of the reals makes this dangerous to assume.

Comment: arctangent can give you such a bijection $(20,35) \to \mathbb{R}$.  Just shift and scale the range values appropriately.

Comment: @Randall I haven't done much work in the inverse trig functions, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Oops, I meant tangent.  Arctangent provides the bijection the other way 'round.

Comment: $f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{x-\frac{55}{2}}{\frac{15}{2}}\right)$. Take away $\frac{55}{2}$ to convert $(20,35)$ into $(-\frac{15}{2}, \frac{15}{2})$, then divide by $\frac{15}{2}$ to map into $(-1,1)$, then multiply by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to map into $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, then apply $\tan$ to map to the whole $\mathbb R$.

Comment: For a proper subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ it is certainly possible for the cardinalities to be equal, for exactly the same reason it is possible in countable cases such as $2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This is a general feature of infinities. In fact (assuming choice), a set is infinite iff it contains a proper subset with the same cardinality as itself. On the other hand, of course the cardinality of a subset of a set is no greater than the cardinality of that s et.

Comment: @Randall, you raise a great point with the $2\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ example

Comment: "Like, for example, we know that |N|<|R| since for any n∈N, we can find an x∈R:n<x<n+1, thus |N|<|R|"  That is *completely* wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can we find a function f:(20,35)→R that maps every element of the domain to the codomain?" Yes.

If $g(x) = \frac {x-20}{15}$ then $g:(20,35)\to (0,1)$ is a bijjection.

And if $h(x)=\pi x - \frac \pi 2$ then $h:(0,1)\to (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ is bijection.

And $\tan:(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2) \to (-\infty, \infty) = \mathbb R$ is a bijection.

So if $f= tan(\frac{x-20}{15}\cdot \pi - \frac \pi 2)=\tan(h(g(x))) $ the $f:(20,35)\to \mathbb R$ is a bijection.

SO $|(20,35)| = |\mathbb R|$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go back to the definition of cardinality to clear up your misunderstandings about the sizes of sets.

Here are some definitions and provable statements that you should understand first.

- Two sets have the same cardinality when there is a bijection between
  them.
- The size of a subset of a set can be no larger than the size of the
  set, because there is an injection from the subset to the set.
- A subset of a set may have the same size as the whole set: there can
  be a bijection even if the natural inclusion injection isn't a
  bijection. The standard first example of this is the argument that
  there are just as many even integers as integers.
- A set is infinite precisely when it is the same size as one of its
  subsets. That tells you there are infinitely many integers.
- There can be infinite sets of different sizes. The class argument due
  to Cantor shows that the size of the set of rational numbers is
  strictly smaller than the size of the reals.

So the answer to the question in the title is the weak inequality: $|X| \le \mathbb{R}$.

Finally this

- Like, for example, we know that |N|<|R| since for any n∈N, we can
  find an x∈R:n<x<n+1, thus |N|<|R|

is a correct conclusion from a false argument. The argument must be wrong since it would apply to show the false result that the size of set of irrational numbers is strictly smaller that that of the reals, since you can always find a rational between any two irrationals.

Answer (score -2):

By definition, a set is infinite if and only if it contains a proper subset with the same cardinality as itself. Put another way:

A set $K$ is infinite $\iff \exists L \subset M, L \neq M : |L|=|M|$

We can see examples of this with $2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$

We can find a bijective function $f: 2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ so that every element of $2\mathbb{Z}$ gets mapped to an element in $\mathbb{Z}$

In the same manner, with the uncountable reals,

For any nonempty proper subset $X \subset \mathbb{R},$ where $X$ is not countable,

Then $|X|=|\mathbb{R}|$

Here, also we can find a bijective function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that every element of $X$ gets mapped to an element in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Do you mean... any $X$? Even $X=\mathbb N$? Even $X=\{0\}$? Even $X=\emptyset$?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and is certainly not uncountable.

Comment: I should say that $X$ is literally scooped up from the real line and nonempty, but defining the reals isn't a simple task. How should I designate it?

Comment: I think you're making this more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @Randall well you're not doing much to help me, now are you?

Comment: I don't see the immediate need to bring in isolated points.  For instance, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a set of isolated points, yet $|\mathbb{Q}| < |\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: "For any nonempty proper subset X⊂R, where X

is not countable,

Then |X|=|R|"  That's not known to be true. That is the continuum hypothesis and it has not be proven.

Comment: @fleablood oh really, nice. I didn’t know that. Sorry about that